# Getting Screensize to measure content

Tags: android, size, screen, device

I'm writing a new book app. I'd like it to run on several devices. The problem I have is `screenSizes`. Is it possible to adjust the amount of text I push into a `textview` to fill up the screen?

So for example, if I have a page on a normal phone, I don't even get 30% filled on a tablet.

I know I can use android folders to determine which screen to use for different sizes, but then I'd have to write 5 extra xml's with different `stringsizes` in the `assetfolder`.

Does anyone know if this is possible? Or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I am understanding your question correctly, but it seems to me like you want to use the `android:width="fill_parent"` and `android:height="fill_parent"` feature to make the textview fill the entire screen of the device.

Comment: This isn't an issue, the issue I have is determining how much text I need to push into the view to fill the entire screen. If I have an xml in assets with Strings that fill up a normal size screen, it will surely not fill a 10inch tab, so what I'm asking is, is it possible to count and see if the screen is filled or not? In case it's not, it should push more text into the view

Comment: You could do `android:width="wrap_content"` so that the textview will fit to the size of its text. Then get the width of the textview in pixels using textView1.getWidth(). Then you get the width of the screen in pixels by using 'MyActivity.this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()'. Then just compare the two sizes and if the width of the textview is less than the width of the screen, you need to add more text.